# Facebook Login Error: "Module XDMConfig has not been defined"

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am getting error "Module XDMConfig has not been defined" on implementing facebook login in Google Chrome, in firefox it is working fine.

How to identify and correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Switching from the debug version to the production version solved this problem for me.